# -moz-overflow: hidden not working in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I need to have Mozilla Firefox specific overflow: hidden property so that it should apply only in Firefox.

[**Fiddle with issue**](https://jsfiddle.net/r4y9c8b6/3/)

Below is the sample code for issue demonstration;

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="hidmeinfirefox">I should be hidden in firefox</div>
</div>

    .container {

}
.container .hidmeinfirefox {
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    -moz-overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I don't recall there's such thing as `-moz-overflow`. Why not simply `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: This is an XY problem. Why do you need it only for firefox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide an html element using javascript only if browser is firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454611/hide-an-html-element-using-javascript-only-if-browser-is-firefox)

Comment: There are dropdown having buttons which are overflowing in firefox only

Comment: @BramVanroy I don't think this question is a duplicate, this is after a CSS method, the linked question was asking for a way to do it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pure CSS solution :

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .container .hidmeinfirefox {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
.container .hidmeinfirefox {
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r4y9c8b6/5/

Comment: Do it have browser support till firefox version 14?

Answer (score 3):

Use this code

```
<style type="text/css">
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .hidmeinfirefox {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
</style>
```